# Json desserializar array para objeto

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

Estou tentando chamar uma API da Web que me retorna um json com múltiplos valores conforme especificado abaixo

**json recebido**

```
[
  {
    "total_documents": 2,
    "total_in_this_page": 2,
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_pages": 1
  },
  {
    "nameDoc": "2.pdf",
    "type": "application/pdf",
    "size": "6053"
  },
  {
    
    "nameDoc": "1.pdf",
    "type": "application/pdf",
    "size": "6053"    
  }
]
```

**Classe documentos info**

```
public class DocumentsInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("total_documents")]
    public int TotalDocuments { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total_in_this_page")]
    public int TotalInThisPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("current_page")]
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total_pages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe documento**

```
public class Document
    {
        public string NameDoc { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
    }
```

**classe documento root**

```
public class Documents
{
    public DocumentsInfo DocumentInfo { get; set; }

    public IList<Document> Documentos { get; set; }
}
```

Estou fazendo da seguinte  maneira e não está funcionando

```
var documents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Documents>>(response.Content);
```

não retorna erro, mas não carrega os objetos

```
[
{
documentInfo: null,
documentos: null
},
{
documentInfo: null,
documentos: null
},
{
documentInfo: null,
documentos: null
}
]
```

Deveria retornar um objeto **documentInfo** e dois **documentos**

Comment: `public IList<Document> Documentos { get; set; }` isso ta errado, olha o json, não retorna uma lista de Documentos, esse json não parece certo, pq ele repete os documentos sem estar num array, o certo seria `[ { "nameDoc": "2.pdf", .... }, { "nameDoc": "1.pdf", ... } ]`, note que para ser um array/lista tem de ter os colchetes. Confirme esse resultado, ele não faz sentido pq, uma hora pode vir 1 ou 2 ou 10 documentos, isso tem de estar num array com `[  ]`, ou o "header" que tem "total_documents" deveria estar fora do `[ ]` no json, assim por exemplo: `{ "total_documents" } [ { "nameDoc" } ]`

Comment: Você tem certeza que a estrutura do JSON é esta? Embora seja sintaticamente válido, este JSON tá bem estranho... O primeiro objeto é completamente diferente dos outros.

Comment: O formato do json está correto, é recebido no formato que está mencionado acima

Comment: se o json é esse mesmo, a estrutra da classe está errada, nunca vai deserializar um objeto para uma IList, a não ser que escreva o seu próprio deserializer ou faça na mão a conversão. De novo, esse json embora seja válido não faz sentido, olhe a documentação dessa API para ver se tem mais informações sobre o contrato